# Not able to connect DocumentDB with springboot(kotlin) application

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, aws-documentdb

Below is my Application yml file

```
authorization:Bearer
spring:
  cache:
    type: redis
  data:
    redis:
      host: localhost
      port: 6379
      database: 1
      connection-timeout: 500
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb://user:password@amazonaws.com:27017/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem&retryWrites=false
      database: docdb
     
server:
  http2:
    enabled: true
  port: 7015
```

I followed this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/connect_programmatically.html#connect_programmatically-tls_enabled to make connection with documentdb

I have created a xyz.sh file for below code and ran in dockerfile

```
mydir=/tmp/certs
truststore=${mydir}/rds-truststore.jks
storepassword=<truststorePassword>

curl -sS "https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.pem" > ${mydir}/global-bundle.pem
awk 'split_after == 1 {n++;split_after=0} /-----END CERTIFICATE-----/ {split_after=1}{print > "rds-ca-" n ".pem"}' < ${mydir}/global-bundle.pem

for CERT in rds-ca-*; do
  alias=$(openssl x509 -noout -text -in $CERT | perl -ne 'next unless /Subject:/; s/.*(CN=|CN = )//; print')
  echo "Importing $alias"
  keytool -import -file ${CERT} -alias "${alias}" -storepass ${storepassword} -keystore ${truststore} -noprompt
  rm $CERT
done

rm ${mydir}/global-bundle.pem

echo "Trust store content is: "

keytool -list -v -keystore "$truststore" -storepass ${storepassword} | grep Alias | cut -d " " -f3- | while read alias 
do
   expiry=`keytool -list -v -keystore "$truststore" -storepass ${storepassword} -alias "${alias}" | grep Valid | perl -ne 'if(/until: (.*?)\n/) { print "$1\n"; }'`
   echo " Certificate ${alias} expires in '$expiry'" 
done
```